# Toggle between three boolean variables in C++

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm tying to make 3 state toggle for my lighting in OpenGL using C++. So the way I want to do it is when LIGHT0 is enabled LIGHT1 and LIGHT2 are disabled. When LIGHT1 is enabled LIGHT0 and LIGHT2 are disabled etc.
I know I can easily toggle between two variables like this:

```
bool light_0 = true, light_1 = false;
if (key press) {
light_0 = !light_0;
light_1 = !light_1; 
}
```

And if I use it for three variables then I'll end up switching one light on and switching two lights off.

Comment: Create a single enum, with three values.

Comment: So I create something like this: enum light {light_0, light_1, light_2}; and then when key is pressed I change the value of enum? Sorry could you please give me some more tips?

Comment: no, you maintain the expected tri-state in the `enum` and then light the right light depending on that state, e.g. `light_0 = (state == show_light_0)`

Comment: Sorry, still don't get what would I do on a key press.

Comment: Change the value of the enum, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a state machine.

You need an enum like suggested:

```
enum Light{
    LIGHT_0, LIGHT_1, LIGHT_2
}
```

Create an instance of Light to keep track of states.

```
 Light lightState = new Light();
```

Whenever you are using your lights you can switch to the current state:

```
useLight(){
    switch(lightState){
        case LIGHT_0:
            //do whatever you want
            break;
        case LIGHT_1:
            //do whatever you want
            break;
        // and so on, customized for your need
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to change light just assing the desired light state to lightState.

```
if(keyPress){
    lightState = LIGHT_1;
}
```

I hope it's understandable now. (It's not a proper c++ syntax)

Comment: Yeah it's really clear now thank you! I used a similar solution:  I just have a Boolean for each light to turn on and off on different keys press. I figured it would be easier to implement and actually even better.